# Handling exceptions thrown by MySQL database on duplicate primary key

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to have an error handler that when I enter an ID in the text box and that ID is already existed in the database it will say. "ID already existed"

Here is my code

```vb
Public Class frmPawn
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection("host=localhost; username=root; password=; database=pawnshop")
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con

        ds = New DataSet
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("insert into clients (clientid, fname, mname, lname, address, city, prov, zip, contact, birth, sex) values('" & txtId.Text & "','" & txtFname.Text & "','" & txtMname.Text & "','" & txtLname.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & txtCity.Text & "','" & txtProv.Text & "','" & txtZip.Text & "','" & txtContact.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker_DOB.Text & "','" & lblSex.Text & "')", con)
        da.Fill(ds, "clients")
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Define the PK column in the database as an AutoIncrement and MySQL will assign a unique PK for you.  Just tick the `AI` column if you use Workbench; I think it is `IDENTITY` in DDL.  Users need not pick the PK

Comment: I use SQLyog for database

Comment: The principle is the same - if the actual DB is MySQL, it supports a AutoIncrement type

Answer (score 1):

I will not discuss how you should really design your system. But here is what you directly asked for

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

     Try
         ' your code here

     Catch mySqlEx As MySqlExeption
         ' Here handle MySql Exceptions
         If mySqlEx.Number = 1068 Then
         . . . . . 
         ' Exception number reference:
         ' http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html
     Catch ex As Exception
          ' Here handle any other Exceptions
     End Try

End Sub
```

As you see, you can use [MySql for .Net documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html) to get all the exception info, which you then handle in your code. The error you receive, I believe the code is 1068. Once you have this code running, you can put break point and check, what the code you receiving and then handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try to select a row from your databse with that said ID, if anything is selected than it already exists, otherwise you can run your code.